# How do I identify the first branch which contains a revisions from the trunk?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving the following:

1) I am examining a particular revision/svn commit in the trunk.
2) I want to find out which release of the software this first went into?

So for example, a user is querying a bug which I know has been fixed.  I identify the revision in the trunk but I want to quickly find the first release branch that contains this.

Currently the way I do this is to look at each branch one by one until I find the first one which contains this revision.

I'm thinking there must be an easier way.  Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both of the above answers go some way to addressing this (thanks for your answers) but I think the bottom line is that there's no easy (one click) way of doing this.

I just happened to stumble across this whilst looking at the future proposed changes for SVN:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3627

Looks as if this area could be improved in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

I'm know this is an old question, but here's what helped me out:

```
svn log -v -r{revision I'm looking for}  {path above trunk and all branches}
```

The "-v" listed out the files changed in that revision, with full paths to the branches.

Answer (score 0):

Try option "Revision graph" which shows the svn tree including trunk/branches/tags with corresponding revision numbers.

Comment: Yes it looks as if I could do it this way although our repository currently has about 7000 revisions so it's quite a large revision graph to navigate.  Maybe I'm just not using the revision graph properly, if I could get it to just show the branches (and not each individual commit) then I could find the first branch after the commit of the fix.

Comment: Right, you can use "filters" for this purpose (for better representation). However, I suppose tortoise needs to index all revisions for the particular path (starting from the creation). It may took considerable time for svn root. But this graph can be regenerated only once per month (for example) and saved in a local file.

Comment: If you need more sophisticated solution, I think you have to write your own perl script to do the task.

Answer (score 0):

The branches and the trunk are in one repository, you could examine the log of the whole repository instead of analyzing separately the trunk and the branches.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r11 | dmitry | 2010-07-23 17:31:26 +0300 (Fri, 23 Jul 2010) | 2 lines

Release 1.0.1 branch

....
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | dmitry | 2010-07-22 19:14:01 +0300 (Thu, 22 Jul 2010) | 1 line

bug x fixed
```

Comment: The question was tagged "tortoisesvn".

Comment: hi, I have tried doing it this way, but due to the number of revisions it's quite a lot to read through.  I guess I could write something to read the history and then find the first branch that has been created after a particular revision.

Comment: @Pmod I don't work with tortoisesvn, but I still think that general svn principles are applicable in it